# Python inheritance/polymorphism

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, base-class

i'm fooling around with this Python Library:

[Read The Docs](https://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

[PopUpDialog](https://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/asciimatics.html#asciimatics.widgets.PopUpDialog)

There is an object named **PopUpDialog** which base class is of **Frame** type.

One of the **fields** of the **Frame** object is **can_scroll=True**.

I would like this **field** to be **False** when I **instantiate** the **PopUpDialog**, so there will be **no scoll bar**.

I tried to make a **new class** named so

```py
class PopUpDialogNoScroll(PopUpDialog):
    super(PopUpdDialogNoScroll, self).__init__(screen,...
```

and

```
class PopUpDialogNoScroll(Frame):
    super(PopUpdDialogNoScroll, self).__init__(screen,...
```

However, all my attempts resulted in an error like *"7 arguments are given 2 are expected"*

Could someone point me out how to **derive a class** and set the fields of a **parent** and/or **grandparent class**?

Thanks and be well

**EDIT**
Thanks to awarrier 99 i got this far, however the scrollbar is still visible. Here I have got some demo code.

```py
from asciimatics.widgets import Frame, ListBox, Layout, Divider, Text, TextBox, Widget, Button, Label, DropdownList, PopUpDialog, CheckBox, RadioButtons, PopupMenu
from asciimatics.scene import Scene
from asciimatics.screen import Screen
from asciimatics.exceptions import ResizeScreenError, NextScene, StopApplication, InvalidFields


class PopUpDialogNoScroll(PopUpDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PopUpDialogNoScroll, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.can_scroll = False
        self.has_border = False


class DemoView(Frame):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(DemoView, self).__init__(screen,
                                          11,
                                          48,
                                          data=None,
                                          on_load=None,
                                          has_border=True,
                                          hover_focus=True,
                                          name=None,
                                          title="Welcome",
                                          x=None,
                                          y=None,
                                          has_shadow=False,
                                          reduce_cpu=False,
                                          is_modal=False,
                                          can_scroll=False)


        body = Layout([1], fill_frame=True)
        self.add_layout(body)
        button = Button("Click me", self.clicked, label=None)
        body.add_widget(button, 0)


    def clicked(self):
      self._scene.add_effect(
          PopUpDialogNoScroll(self.screen, "1..\n2..\n3..\n4..\n5..  ", ["OK"], on_close=self.done, has_shadow=False, theme='info'))

    def done(self):
        pass


last_scene = None

def demo(screen, scene):
  scenes = [
    Scene([DemoView(screen)], duration=-1, clear=True, name="demo"),
  ]

  screen.play(scenes, stop_on_resize=False, unhandled_input=None, start_scene=scene, repeat=True, allow_int=True)

Screen.wrapper(demo, catch_interrupt=True, arguments=[last_scene])
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: python 2.7,  developing. python 3 to use it when it's done

Comment: Looking at the docs more, the fact that it mentions that PopUpDialog is a fixed implementation Frame I think means that you can't change the properties of the initial Frame object. And since PopUpDialog doesn't provide a parameter for can_scroll, I don't think it's possible for a PopUpDialog to not have a scroll bar, you may have to extend Frame directly and implement your own version if you want to remove the scroll bar

Comment: Look at my updated answer to see an example of how to implement your own `PopUpDialogNoScroll` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, any calls to a super should be made in the first line of the class's own `__init__` function. So your class should have its own `__init__` function. Then, to pass all the parameters you want to the original class, you can provide two arguments to incorporate all of the arguments that the inherited class would have: `*args` and `**kwargs`. Then, you can explicitly set the can_scroll field to False in the `__init__` function, like so:

```
class PopUpDialogNoScroll(PopUpDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PopUpDialogNoScroll, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.can_scroll = False
```

By having `*args` and `**kwargs`, you can pass in any parameters that the original `PopUpDialog` class would expect without having to explicitly rewrite them and you can provide them to the `super` class

**Edit**:
When you migrate your code over to Python 3, you can change the `super` call to the following which is new syntax in Python 3: `super().__init(*args, **kwargs)`. Note that the only difference is that you don't have to explicitly specify the class name and the `self` reference

**Edit 2**:
Looking at the source provided [here](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics/blob/master/asciimatics/widgets.py), I was able to make a `PopUpDialogNoScroll` class by copying whatever code they had used for their `PopUpDialog` class, and then changing this line from their source:

`super(PopUpDialog, self).__init__(screen, height, width, self._data, has_shadow=has_shadow, is_modal=True)`

to:

`super(PopUpDialogNoScroll, self).__init__(screen, height, width, self._data, has_shadow=has_shadow, is_modal=True, can_scroll=False)`

Not the most elegant of solutions, but it works

```
from asciimatics.widgets import Frame, ListBox, Layout, Divider, Text, TextBox, Widget, Button, Label, DropdownList, PopUpDialog, CheckBox, RadioButtons, PopupMenu
from asciimatics.scene import Scene
from asciimatics.screen import Screen
from asciimatics.exceptions import ResizeScreenError, NextScene, StopApplication, InvalidFields
from wcwidth import wcswidth
from functools import partial

def _enforce_width(text, width, unicode_aware=True):
    """
    Enforce a displayed piece of text to be a certain number of cells wide.  This takes into
    account double-width characters used in CJK languages.
    :param text: The text to be truncated
    :param width: The screen cell width to enforce
    :return: The resulting truncated text
    """
    # Double-width strings cannot be more than twice the string length, so no need to try
    # expensive truncation if this upper bound isn't an issue.
    if (2 * len(text) < width) or (len(text) < width and not unicode_aware):
        return text

    # Can still optimize performance if we are not handling unicode characters.
    if unicode_aware:
        size = 0
        for i, c in enumerate(str(text)):
            w = wcwidth(c) if ord(c) >= 256 else 1
            if size + w > width:
                return text[0:i]
            size += w
    elif len(text) + 1 > width:
        return text[0:width]
    return text

def _split_text(text, width, height, unicode_aware=True):
    """
    Split text to required dimensions.
    This will first try to split the text into multiple lines, then put a "..." on the last
    3 characters of the last line if this still doesn't fit.
    :param text: The text to split.
    :param width: The maximum width for any line.
    :param height: The maximum height for the resulting text.
    :return: A list of strings of the broken up text.
    """
    # At a high level, just try to split on whitespace for the best results.
    tokens = text.split(" ")
    result = []
    current_line = ""
    string_len = wcswidth if unicode_aware else len
    for token in tokens:
        for i, line_token in enumerate(token.split("\n")):
            if string_len(current_line + line_token) > width or i > 0:
                # Don't bother inserting completely blank lines - which should only happen on the very first
                # line (as the rest will inject whitespace/newlines)
                if len(current_line) > 0:
                    result.append(current_line.rstrip())
                current_line = line_token + " "
            else:
                current_line += line_token + " "

    # At this point we've either split nicely or have a hugely long unbroken string (e.g. because the
    # language doesn't use whitespace.  Either way, break this last line up as best we can.
    current_line = current_line.rstrip()
    while string_len(current_line) > 0:
        new_line = _enforce_width(current_line, width, unicode_aware)
        result.append(new_line)
        current_line = current_line[len(new_line):]

    # Check for a height overrun and truncate.
    if len(result) > height:
        result = result[:height]
        result[height - 1] = result[height - 1][:width - 3] + "..."

    # Very small columns could be shorter than individual words - truncate
    # each line if necessary.
    for i, line in enumerate(result):
        if len(line) > width:
            result[i] = line[:width - 3] + "..."
    return result

class PopUpDialogNoScroll(Frame):
    """
    A fixed implementation Frame that provides a standard message box dialog.
    """

    def __init__(self, screen, text, buttons, on_close=None, has_shadow=False, theme="warning"):
        """
        :param screen: The Screen that owns this dialog.
        :param text: The message text to display.
        :param buttons: A list of button names to display. This may be an empty list.
        :param on_close: Optional function to invoke on exit.
        :param has_shadow: optional flag to specify if dialog should have a shadow when drawn.
        :param theme: optional colour theme for this pop-up.  Defaults to the warning colours.
        The `on_close` method (if specified) will be called with one integer parameter that
        corresponds to the index of the button passed in the array of available `buttons`.
        Note that `on_close` must be a static method to work across screen resizing.  Either it
        is static (and so the dialog will be cloned) or it is not (and the dialog will disappear
        when the screen is resized).
        """
        # Remember parameters for cloning.
        self._text = text
        self._buttons = buttons
        self._on_close = on_close

        # Decide on optimum width of the dialog.  Limit to 2/3 the screen width.
        string_len = wcswidth if screen.unicode_aware else len
        width = max([string_len(x) for x in text.split("\n")])
        width = max(width + 2,
                    sum([string_len(x) + 4 for x in buttons]) + len(buttons) + 5)
        width = min(width, screen.width * 2 // 3)

        # Figure out the necessary message and allow for buttons and borders
        # when deciding on height.
        dh = 4 if len(buttons) > 0 else 2
        self._message = _split_text(text, width - 2, screen.height - dh, screen.unicode_aware)
        height = len(self._message) + dh

        # Construct the Frame
        self._data = {"message": self._message}
        super(PopUpDialogNoScroll, self).__init__(
            screen, height, width, self._data, has_shadow=has_shadow, is_modal=True, can_scroll=False)

        # Build up the message box
        layout = Layout([width - 2], fill_frame=True)
        self.add_layout(layout)
        text_box = TextBox(len(self._message), name="message")
        text_box.disabled = True
        layout.add_widget(text_box)
        layout2 = Layout([1 for _ in buttons])
        self.add_layout(layout2)
        for i, button in enumerate(buttons):
            func = partial(self._destroy, i)
            layout2.add_widget(Button(button, func), i)
        self.fix()

        # Ensure that we have the right palette in place
        self.set_theme(theme)

    def _destroy(self, selected):
        self._scene.remove_effect(self)
        if self._on_close:
            self._on_close(selected)

    def clone(self, screen, scene):
        """
        Create a clone of this Dialog into a new Screen.
        :param screen: The new Screen object to clone into.
        :param scene: The new Scene object to clone into.
        """
        # Only clone the object if the function is safe to do so.
        if self._on_close is None or isfunction(self._on_close):
            scene.add_effect(PopUpDialog(screen, self._text, self._buttons, self._on_close))

class DemoView(Frame):
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(DemoView, self).__init__(screen,
                                          11,
                                          48,
                                          data=None,
                                          on_load=None,
                                          has_border=True,
                                          hover_focus=True,
                                          name=None,
                                          title="Welcome",
                                          x=None,
                                          y=None,
                                          has_shadow=False,
                                          reduce_cpu=False,
                                          is_modal=False,
                                          can_scroll=False)


        body = Layout([1], fill_frame=True)
        self.add_layout(body)
        button = Button("Click me", self.clicked, label=None)
        body.add_widget(button, 0)


    def clicked(self):
      self._scene.add_effect(
          PopUpDialogNoScroll(self.screen, "1..\n2..\n3..\n4..\n5..  ", ["OK"], on_close=self.done, has_shadow=False, theme='info'))

    def done(self):
        pass


last_scene = None

def demo(screen, scene):
  scenes = [
    Scene([DemoView(screen)], duration=-1, clear=True, name="demo"),
  ]

  screen.play(scenes, stop_on_resize=False, unhandled_input=None, start_scene=scene, repeat=True, allow_int=True)

Screen.wrapper(demo, catch_interrupt=True, arguments=[last_scene])
```